# Export File Excel DateFormat issue

Tags: laravel

I try to format tow date columns in my excel file wish is the column dt_naissance and created_at

i get this exception when i try to run the code :

> [ERROR] Laravel Worksheet method [formatDates] does not exist.

Here my code :

```
$licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')
            ->leftJoin('activite_licencie' , 'activite_licencie.id' , '=' , 'licencies.activite_licencie_id')
            ->leftJoin('saisons' , 'saisons.id' , '=' , 'licencies.saison_id')
            ->leftJoin('pays' , 'pays.id' , '=' , 'licencies.pays_naissance_id')
            ->leftJoin('type_licence' , 'type_licence.id' , '=' , 'licencies.type_licence_id')
            ->leftJoin('structures' , 'structures.id' , '=' , 'licencies.structure_id')
            ->select('num_licence' , 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'dt_naissance' , 'pays.fr' ,'activite_licencie.lb_activite'  ,'saisons.lb_saison', 'lb_surclassement' ,  'structures.nom_structure' , 'lb_assurance' , 'cd_dept_naissance' , 'licencies.created_at')
            ->whereRaw('DATE(licencies.created_at) = CURRENT_DATE')
            ->get();

            $excel_file = Excel::create('DailyRecapLicencesLafont', function($excel) use ($licencies) {
            $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($licencies);
                $sheet->formatDates(true , 'd-m-Y');


                $sheet->setDateColumns(array(
                    'dt_naissance',
                    'created_at'
                ))->get();

            });

        });
```

Someone now why i get this error ? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatDates` is a [reader](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/46f1f9168202877d2d9c570042af315567b268c0/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Readers/LaravelExcelReader.php) method of an Excel sheet. It is not a Worksheet method.

When reading an Excel file, you can use the method like this:

```
Excel::load($pathToExcelFile)->formatDates(true, 'd-m-Y');
```

To set the format of a column when writing to a file, you can use `setColumnFormat()`. For example ([Laravel Excel 2.1](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/format.html)):

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('A1:A10' => 'd-m-Y'));
```

Or, in ([Laravel Excel >=3.0](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#formatting-columns)), you can add the `columnFormats` method to your export class:

```
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DMYMINUS,
    ];
}
```

For a full list of available formats, take a look at [PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.php)

Comment: thanks for the answer ! and if i would like to change the format when i store the file ?

Comment: i want to use it but to store the file not to load it because the file is later send by email

Comment: You can use `setColumnFormat()`. For example `$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('A1:A10' => 'd-m-Y'));`

Comment: Not Working 
Method Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet::setColumnFormat does not exist.

Comment: @mamenaware Updated the answer for Laravel Excel >=3.0.